# WinHTTP Async Callback

Tags: c++, winapi, winhttp

I'm not very good in C++, you if you see something in the code fragment which could be better, please educate me!

I'm implementing winhttp in an asynchronous fashion. But im having trouble retrieving the response. I cant figure it out. Because you should be able to parsethe whole response at once. Since multiple concurent request can occur, buffering the response (headers+body) in a global variable is not the way to go.

How can I retrieve the response of the http get request? Or else, is it an good practice to execute winhttp synchronous on a new thread (so the main loop doesn;t get blocked and then calls a function when done?):

```
     void __stdcall cb(HINTERNET h, DWORD_PTR d, DWORD dwInternetStatus, LPVOID lpvStatusInformation, DWORD dwStatusInformationLength){ 
         char* s=new char[1];

             DWORD dwSize = 0;
             if (dwInternetStatus==WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_DATA_AVAILABLE){
                                 MessageBoxA(0,s,"",0);

                WinHttpQueryDataAvailable( h, &dwSize);
                .....

             }

 }
```

And the call in the main:

```
...winhttpopen...
WinHttpSetStatusCallback(request, (WINHTTP_STATUS_CALLBACK)whCallback,WINHTTP_CALLBACK_FLAG_ALL_NOTIFICATIONS,0);
...winhttpsend....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this sample code on MSDN - [Asynchronous Completion in WinHTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383138%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> The call to WinHttpQueryDataAvailable in QueryData generates a status
>   callback with a `WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_DATA_AVAILABLE` completion in
>   the dwInternetStatus parameter. By checking the value pointed to by
>   the lpvStatusInformation parameter, the callback can determine how
>   much data is left to be read, and if there is no remaining data, can
>   proceed to display all the data that has been read.

This shows you that your callback is called with buffer pointer and length of data in it.

Comment: If you have experience with winhttp and can give a hand :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577503/winhttp-used-in-async-mode-error-internet-cannot-connect-how-to-cleanly-close

Comment: It's funny how the **Asynchronous Completion in WinHTTP** documentation give an example of everything - except the asynchronous callback.